# Invalid request error from server in android

Tags: php, android, json, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send credentials to my server but my PHP file returns:

> {"errors":["invalid_request"]}

My code:

```
                JSONObject jsonObjectToSend = new JSONObject();
                jsonObjectToSend.put("email",credentials[0].toString());
                jsonObjectToSend.put("password",credentials[1].toString());

                String message = jsonObjectToSend.toString();

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                URL url = new URL("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/user/login.php");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                conn.connect();
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(message);
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                //Getting the response from the server when we try to login.

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                result = sb.toString();
```

The JSON format that I need to pass is:

```
{
 "email": "example@gmail.com",
 "password": "123456789" 
}
```

But I don't know which method (POST or GET) is being used in the PHP script. I have tried both methods but got the same error.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the raw request body?

```file_get_contents('php://input');```

Comment: @CarlosCarucce yes but same error

Comment: did you test this API via something else? Say Postman?

Comment: @georaldc means to directly type in the web browser or use any application like Rest Web Service Client or similar??

Comment: @Vucko Same error getting in the Postman. But may be i am filling the wrong fields. Will you please tell the right fields that i need to fill.

Comment: This just means that your request is not good. Is it your API or? You need to find out what data your request should have exactly. This is not the android causing the error.

Comment: @Vucko means i am not passing the right parameters or proper format??

Comment: Yes, basically. Not the Json API is expecting.

Comment: Your server code might be more relevant here, as that's where the error is coming from. What is causing the error in the first place? You should know if you designed the server API yourself.